SAP CAP Multitenant - getDependencies callback error
I am working on a multitenant application using SAP CAP. When trying to subscribe a tenant, I am getting a 403 Forbidden as callback as shown below.

Subscribe failed. Error: Subscribe failed. Failed to call callback. URL: GET https://ff28e96ftrial-dev-mtxs-bookshop-srv.cfapps.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com/-/cds/saas-provisioning/dependencies?tenantId=87713070-f11e-432a-8e07-68bd4233c24e. Consumer tenant: 87713070-f11e-432a-8e07-68bd4233c24e. Callback response: {"error":{"code":"403","message":"Forbidden"}}. status code: 403 FORBIDDEN

I have tried to redeploy my application, changed my roles but to no avail. Its working locally in SAP BAS but it gets this error when I tried to deploy and subscribe an actual tenant

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
